# How to add additional fields to register page in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add a few extra fields to the register page in the default asp.net mvc application that we get when we open visual studio. I followed this tutorial.

[Customize MVC 5 Register Page](http://blog.falafel.com/customize-mvc-5-application-users-using-asp-net-identity-2-0/)

These are the steps that I followed after opening the default project that we get in Visual studio for asp.net MVC.

1. First I ran the project and clicked on Register button and registered a random user. I did this so that the default database would get created.

   [image]

   2. Now that the database was generated, I went to the database and added extra columns like Gender, Birthday, FirstName, LastName and AboutUser and re-updated the database table called ASPNETUSERS.

   [image]

   3. Now I went to RegisterViewModel and added these same properties as well.

   [image]

   4. After that I went to ApplicationUser and added the same properties as well.

   [image]

   5. After that I changed the view for Register.cshtml to incorporate extra textboxes, textareas for the new fields that I created.
   6. Now I went to the controller and added these properties in as well. Everything seems fine to me so far, except the fact that the database's definition changed from the beginning.

   [image]

This is how the page looks after all these changes.

[image]

Now I ran the project and tried to register a person, but I keep getting this error.

[image]

I researched about this error, but the solutions suggest that I should try adding `Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);` in the constructor of myDBContext. But the thing is, I don't have any context at all. So this solution doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You shouldn't modify the DB directly. I'd suggest you delete the fields you added and follow [@Latvian's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38647431/237917)

Comment: So I have to do that thing first and then change my database structure? or can I do that now to fix this?

Comment: No, migrations are how you're supposed to change the database schema. Add the properties to `ApplicationUser` as you have, then run the migration steps. You might have to run `enable-migrations` first. You'll want to read up on Code First.

Comment: So I should first add my columns to the .mdf database file, then to the application user and then run migrations? or do I need to do it before adding extra columns in database .mdf file?

Comment: You shouldn't touch the database at all. Use the migrations

Comment: I will read up on that for sure. But it worked after doing some tweaking. For others, this is what I did.  I tried `add-migration <YourNewMigrationName>`, I got a warning, so I tried `enable-migrations`, then I got another error, then I did `Enable-Migrations EnableAutomaticMigrations`, which created a folder but updating didn't work, so then again I did `Add-Migration InitialMigration –IgnoreChanges` and `Update-Database` and now it works. TLDR : `Add-Migration InitialMigration –IgnoreChanges` and `Update-Database` is all you need. Although I don't know what happened here.

Comment: `-IgnoreChanges` just tells the migrations to skip the schema check. In your next project do `enable-migrations` first and you won't have that issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you change any entity in solution, you should change your db (so your object model equals your db model).

In this case you should open nuget package console (service > nuget > console) and use:

```
       add-migration <YourNewMigrationName>
```

and after new migration created (code for change your db model), you have to accept it:

```
       update-database
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the record added to migration table

Answer (score 0):

Delete your Migrations Folder And Reapply migrations

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33612983)